# What is gradient of $|f(x)|^p f(x)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb C$ and $g:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ such that $g(z)=|z|^pz$ for some $p>1.$ Then the composition function $g\circ f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb C$ is such that $g\circ f (x)= |f(x)|^p f(x).$

> My question is: What is the gradient of $g\circ f$? In other words, what is $\nabla (g\circ f)$? If $p=4/(d-2), d\geq 3,$ can we say $|\nabla (g\circ f)| \leq C |(\nabla f)| |f|^{4/(d-2)}$ where $C$ some constant.

Comment: The gradient is typically defined for functions $h \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$.  I'm not sure what you mean by the gradient of a function $h \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$.  However, you can take the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) of a function $h \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^2$.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: @JesseMadnick: Thanks.  the question comes out of my try to understand: equations  (1.5) in following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0507005.pdf)

Comment: I'm wondering, in that equation (1.5) (chain rule), how does one make sense of $\nabla u$? (since $u$ is a complexed valued function)